# Class 'QueryParameterComparer' must implement Function Compare.

Tags: vb.net

Im getting the following error on the code I transleted from C# to VB.NET below (original code can be found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/sites/default/files/LinkedInAuth.rar.zip):

Class 'QueryParameterComparer' must implement 'Function Compare(x As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter, y As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter) As Integer' for interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of QueryParameter)'.

What exactly do I need to change?

---

'
' This file was modified by Fatih YASAR at 27.11.2009
'

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web


Public Class oAuthBase2

''' <summary>
''' Provides a predefined set of algorithms that are supported officially by the protocol
''' </summary>
Public Enum SignatureTypes
    HMACSHA1
    PLAINTEXT
    RSASHA1
End Enum

''' <summary>
''' Provides an internal structure to sort the query parameter
''' </summary>
Protected Class QueryParameter
    Private m_name As String = Nothing
    Private m_value As String = Nothing

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
        Me.m_name = name
        Me.m_value = value
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return m_value
        End Get
    End Property
End Class


Protected Class QueryParameterComparer
    Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of oAuthBase2.QueryParameter)

#Region "IComparer<QueryParameter> Members"

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter, ByVal y As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter) As Integer
        If x.Name = y.Name Then
            Return String.Compare(x.Value, y.Value)
        Else
            Return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name)
        End If
    End Function

#End Region
End Class


Protected Const OAuthVersion As String = "1.0"
Protected Const OAuthParameterPrefix As String = "oauth_"

'
' List of know and used oauth parameters' names
'        
Protected Const OAuthConsumerKeyKey As String = "oauth_consumer_key"
Protected Const OAuthCallbackKey As String = "oauth_callback"
Protected Const OAuthVersionKey As String = "oauth_version"
Protected Const OAuthSignatureMethodKey As String = "oauth_signature_method"
Protected Const OAuthSignatureKey As String = "oauth_signature"
Protected Const OAuthTimestampKey As String = "oauth_timestamp"
Protected Const OAuthNonceKey As String = "oauth_nonce"
Protected Const OAuthTokenKey As String = "oauth_token"
Protected Const oAauthVerifier As String = "oauth_verifier"
Protected Const OAuthTokenSecretKey As String = "oauth_token_secret"

Protected Const HMACSHA1SignatureType As String = "HMAC-SHA1"
Protected Const PlainTextSignatureType As String = "PLAINTEXT"
Protected Const RSASHA1SignatureType As String = "RSA-SHA1"

Protected random As New Random()

Private oauth_verifier As String
Public Property Verifier() As String
    Get
        Return oauth_verifier
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        oauth_verifier = value
    End Set
End Property


Protected unreservedChars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~"

''' <summary>
''' Helper function to compute a hash value
''' </summary>
''' <param name="hashAlgorithm">The hashing algoirhtm used. If that algorithm needs some initialization, like HMAC and its derivatives, they should be initialized prior to passing it to this function</param>
''' <param name="data">The data to hash</param>
''' <returns>a Base64 string of the hash value</returns>
Private Function ComputeHash(ByVal hashAlgorithm As HashAlgorithm, ByVal data As String) As String
    If hashAlgorithm Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("hashAlgorithm")
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("data")
    End If

    Dim dataBuffer As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
    Dim hashBytes As Byte() = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataBuffer)

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Internal function to cut out all non oauth query string parameters (all parameters not begining with "oauth_")
''' </summary>
''' <param name="parameters">The query string part of the Url</param>
''' <returns>A list of QueryParameter each containing the parameter name and value</returns>
Private Function GetQueryParameters(ByVal parameters As String) As List(Of QueryParameter)
    If parameters.StartsWith("?") Then
        parameters = parameters.Remove(0, 1)
    End If

    Dim result As New List(Of QueryParameter)()

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters) Then
        Dim p As String() = parameters.Split("&"c)
        For Each s As String In p
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) AndAlso Not s.StartsWith(OAuthParameterPrefix) Then
                If s.IndexOf("="c) > -1 Then
                    Dim temp As String() = s.Split("="c)
                    result.Add(New QueryParameter(temp(0), temp(1)))
                Else
                    result.Add(New QueryParameter(s, String.Empty))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return result
End Function

''' <summary>
''' This is a different Url Encode implementation since the default .NET one outputs the percent encoding in lower case.
''' While this is not a problem with the percent encoding spec, it is used in upper case throughout OAuth
''' </summary>
''' <param name="value">The value to Url encode</param>
''' <returns>Returns a Url encoded string</returns>
Public Function UrlEncode(ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim result As New StringBuilder()

    For Each symbol As Char In value
        If unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) <> -1 Then
            result.Append(symbol)
        Else
            result.Append("%"c & [String].Format("{0:X2}", AscW(symbol)))
        End If
    Next

    Return result.ToString()
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Normalizes the request parameters according to the spec
''' </summary>
''' <param name="parameters">The list of parameters already sorted</param>
''' <returns>a string representing the normalized parameters</returns>
Protected Function NormalizeRequestParameters(ByVal parameters As IList(Of QueryParameter)) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim p As QueryParameter = Nothing
    For i As Integer = 0 To parameters.Count - 1
        p = parameters(i)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", p.Name, p.Value)

        If i < parameters.Count - 1 Then
            sb.Append("&")
        End If
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Generate the signature base that is used to produce the signature
''' </summary>
''' <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
''' <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>        
''' <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
''' <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
''' <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
''' <param name="signatureType">The signature type. To use the default values use <see cref="OAuthBase.SignatureTypes">OAuthBase.SignatureTypes</see>.</param>
''' <returns>The signature base</returns>
Public Function GenerateSignatureBase(ByVal url As Uri, ByVal consumerKey As String, ByVal token As String, ByVal tokenSecret As String, ByVal httpMethod As String, ByVal timeStamp As String, _
 ByVal nonce As String, ByVal signatureType As String, ByRef normalizedUrl As String, ByRef normalizedRequestParameters As String) As String
    If token Is Nothing Then
        token = String.Empty
    End If

    If tokenSecret Is Nothing Then
        tokenSecret = String.Empty
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("consumerKey")
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(httpMethod) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("httpMethod")
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureType) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("signatureType")
    End If

    normalizedUrl = Nothing
    normalizedRequestParameters = Nothing

    Dim parameters As List(Of QueryParameter) = GetQueryParameters(url.Query)
    parameters.Add(New QueryParameter(OAuthVersionKey, OAuthVersion))
    parameters.Add(New QueryParameter(OAuthNonceKey, nonce))
    parameters.Add(New QueryParameter(OAuthTimestampKey, timeStamp))
    parameters.Add(New QueryParameter(OAuthSignatureMethodKey, signatureType))
    parameters.Add(New QueryParameter(OAuthConsumerKeyKey, consumerKey))

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(token) Then
        parameters.Add(New QueryParameter(OAuthTokenKey, token))
    End If

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oauth_verifier) Then
        parameters.Add(New QueryParameter(oAauthVerifier, oauth_verifier))
    End If


    parameters.Sort(New QueryParameterComparer())


    normalizedUrl = String.Format("{0}://{1}", url.Scheme, url.Host)
    If Not ((url.Scheme = "http" AndAlso url.Port = 80) OrElse (url.Scheme = "https" AndAlso url.Port = 443)) Then
        normalizedUrl += ":" & url.Port
    End If
    normalizedUrl += url.AbsolutePath
    normalizedRequestParameters = NormalizeRequestParameters(parameters)

    Dim signatureBase As New StringBuilder()
    signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}&", httpMethod.ToUpper())
    signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}&", UrlEncode(normalizedUrl))
    signatureBase.AppendFormat("{0}", UrlEncode(normalizedRequestParameters))

    Return signatureBase.ToString()
End Function


''' <summary>
''' Generate the signature value based on the given signature base and hash algorithm
''' </summary>
''' <param name="signatureBase">The signature based as produced by the GenerateSignatureBase method or by any other means</param>
''' <param name="hash">The hash algorithm used to perform the hashing. If the hashing algorithm requires initialization or a key it should be set prior to calling this method</param>
''' <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
Public Function GenerateSignatureUsingHash(ByVal signatureBase As String, ByVal hash As HashAlgorithm) As String
    Return ComputeHash(hash, signatureBase)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Generates a signature using the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm
''' </summary>      
''' <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
''' <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>
''' <param name="consumerSecret">The consumer seceret</param>
''' <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
''' <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
''' <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
''' <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
Public Function GenerateSignature(ByVal url As Uri, ByVal consumerKey As String, ByVal consumerSecret As String, ByVal token As String, ByVal tokenSecret As String, ByVal httpMethod As String, _
 ByVal timeStamp As String, ByVal nonce As String, ByRef normalizedUrl As String, ByRef normalizedRequestParameters As String) As String
    Return GenerateSignature(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, _
     timeStamp, nonce, SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, normalizedUrl, normalizedRequestParameters)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Generates a signature using the specified signatureType 
''' </summary>      
''' <param name="url">The full url that needs to be signed including its non OAuth url parameters</param>
''' <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key</param>
''' <param name="consumerSecret">The consumer seceret</param>
''' <param name="token">The token, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
''' <param name="tokenSecret">The token secret, if available. If not available pass null or an empty string</param>
''' <param name="httpMethod">The http method used. Must be a valid HTTP method verb (POST,GET,PUT, etc)</param>
''' <param name="signatureType">The type of signature to use</param>
''' <returns>A base64 string of the hash value</returns>
Public Function GenerateSignature(ByVal url As Uri, ByVal consumerKey As String, ByVal consumerSecret As String, ByVal token As String, ByVal tokenSecret As String, ByVal httpMethod As String, _
 ByVal timeStamp As String, ByVal nonce As String, ByVal signatureType As SignatureTypes, ByRef normalizedUrl As String, ByRef normalizedRequestParameters As String) As String
    normalizedUrl = Nothing
    normalizedRequestParameters = Nothing

    Select Case signatureType
        Case SignatureTypes.PLAINTEXT
            Return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerSecret, tokenSecret))
        Case SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1
            Dim signatureBase As String = GenerateSignatureBase(url, consumerKey, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, _
             nonce, HMACSHA1SignatureType, normalizedUrl, normalizedRequestParameters)

            Dim hmacsha1 As New HMACSHA1()
            hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}&{1}", UrlEncode(consumerSecret), If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenSecret), "", UrlEncode(tokenSecret))))

            Return GenerateSignatureUsingHash(signatureBase, hmacsha1)
        Case SignatureTypes.RSASHA1
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Unknown signature type", "signatureType")
    End Select
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Generate the timestamp for the signature        
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>

Public Overridable Function GenerateTimeStamp() As String
    ' Default implementation of UNIX time of the current UTC time
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, _
     0)
    Return Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString()
End Function

'
'      public virtual string GenerateTimeStamp() {
'          // Default implementation of UNIX time of the current UTC time
'          TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
'          string timeStamp = ts.TotalSeconds.ToString();
'          timeStamp = timeStamp.Substring(0, timeStamp.IndexOf(","));
'          return Convert.ToInt64(timeStamp).ToString(); 
'      }


''' <summary>
''' Generate a nonce
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Overridable Function GenerateNonce() As String
    ' Just a simple implementation of a random number between 123400 and 9999999
    Return random.[Next](123400, 9999999).ToString()
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
Public Function Compare(ByVal x As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter, ByVal y As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter) As Integer
```

to:

```
Public Function Compare(ByVal x As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter, ByVal y As oAuthBase2.QueryParameter) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of oAuthBase2.QueryParameter).Compare
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up here looking for help with implementing an interface in VB.NET. For some reason I had to use this syntax for the function:

```
Public Function MethodName1 As String Implements IInterfaceName.Methodname
```

I only found out this syntax when I pressed enter (specifically) after typing the interface name and it created this automatically for me.

Might help someone else running into similar problems as me!